# How to update parent form from child form in vb6?

Tags: forms, vb6

I have a parent form that opens a modal child form. 
The child form has 2 buttons - okay and cancel. I would like to call the corresponding events in the parent form. Any ideas how I can do that?

I thought that I have to pass the parent form object when calling `Show` on the child, but it doesn't seem to help.

This is the code that I have in the parent form:

```
answerFromChild = "NothingReceivedYet" 'it's a public property that should get updated 
                                         'to "Okay" when the okay button 
                                         'in the child form is clicked.

Dim myChildForm2 As New ChildForm2
myChildForm2.setVariableOne = "Test"
myChildForm2.Show vbModal, Me

If answerFromChild <> "Okay" Then Exit Sub

'there is more code if it says "Okay"
```

The above code in the parent works, but the `answerFromChild` property never gets updated to "Okay".

This is the code in the child form:

```
Private Sub Okay_Click()
    ParentForm1.answerFromChild = "Okay" 'this works but it updates 
                                         'the "answerFromChild" in 
                                         'another instance of the ParentForm1
    Unload Me
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A better design would be to declare a `Public Event` on the child form that the parent adds handlers for.  Then you `RaiseEvent` in the child and that will trigger code execution in the parent which should then update its own form elements.

In child:-

```
'Declare the event that will broadcast the message to whoever is listening
Public Event SomethingImportantEvent(message As String)

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  'Tell whoever is interested
  RaiseEvent SomethingImportantEvent("Hello from child")
End Sub
```

In parent:-

```
Dim WithEvents child As Form2

Private Sub child_SomethingImportantEvent(message As String)
  Debug.Print "The child said: " & message
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  If child Is Nothing Then
    set child = New Form2
  End If
  child.Show
End Sub
```

Comment: Good idea, but I get a `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set` at `child.Show`

Comment: Did you missed the `New` keyword that I used in my code?  `Dim WithEvents child As New Form2`

Comment: @joehanna You cannot use `WithEvents` with `New` declaration. For `WithEvents` OP will need explicit allocation.

Comment: Thanks @wqw. I tried it in a VBA environment and it worked fine.  I didn't expect VB6 to be any different.  @Apostrofix - I have updated my answer to instantiate the `child` object.